# highlighting text in menu using <ul class> in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to call a a div id function in CSS so that when my mouse hovers over the text it highlights it

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1721" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1721"><a href="http://18.205.33.160/index.php/services/strategic-it-consulting/?customize_changeset_uuid=924e99ff-4237-48e6-8ab2-5902b4e0b6c1&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" target="_self">Strategic IT Consulting</a></li>
```

is there a way to call this for all sub-menus in the ul class using CSS?

```
.sub-menu:hover {
color:green
}
```

Comment: Don't understand - Like `.sub-menu:hover li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sub-menu li a:hover {
    color:green
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you! I will mark as correct, but it says I have to wait 9 minutes before I am allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mark tag around the text

```css
mark:hover {
background-color:green
}
mark
{
background-color:white
}
```

```html
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-1721" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1721"><a href="http://18.205.33.160/index.php/services/strategic-it-consulting/?customize_changeset_uuid=924e99ff-4237-48e6-8ab2-5902b4e0b6c1&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" target="_self"><mark>Strategic IT Consulting</mark></a></li>
```

Comment: This is a wrong usage of the `<mark>` tag - Read the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element): _"...  When used in the main prose of a document, **it indicates** a part of the document that has been highlighted due to its **likely relevance to the user's current activity**."_ - So you can use span, but not recommending the mark tag